# Many-To-One relationships in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am still trying to learn NHibernate best practices, so please be easy on me...  :-)

I have a Product class with a Many-To-One relationship set up to a Category class.  On my Add A Product page, I am loading a DropDownList with the Categories.  Now when the user enters the product information and clicks submit, I have to pull down the Category by ID (DropDownList SelectedValue) from the database to populate the Category property of my Product object so I can save it.

It seems like the Category by ID lookup is a waste.  Is there a way I can simply use the ID value that was retrieved from the DropDownList?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ISession.Load() to create a proxy object.  eg:

```
myProduct.Category = session.Load<Category>(userSuppliedCategoryId);
```

Note that the Load() method doesn't actually hit the database unless you try accessing a property besides the primary key, so there is no extra DB hit.

[Ayende has a good post about this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx)